# Is there a clean way to quit evim?

Tags: linux, vim

While fiddling with installation of `vim` and `gvim` from source, trying to release console-based `vim` from X dependencies, I tried to run `evim` to see what it is and whether it should be freed from X dependencies. It started in terminal, and I saw that it's always in insert mode. I soon understood that it's the so called "Easy Vim".

OK, now I want to quit it and... well, `:q` doesn't work because of insert mode, `<Ctrl>+[` or `ESC` refuse to go to normal mode. I simply can't enter any command. Trying `<Ctrl>+C`, `<Ctrl>+Z`, even `<Ctrl>+\` doesn't let me break out of it. Finally I went to another terminal and did `killall evim`, which succeeded.

So, the question: is there a *clean* way to quit console-based `evim`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> will get back to normal vim mode.  You can then use the usual `:q`